# MVC3 Internationalization data annotations

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, localization, data-annotations

We're currently migrating an existing application to ASP.NET MVC 3. We're reusing the database schema which contains all of our resources in the database rather than resx files.

We have a ResourceProvider that acts as a facade around the resource repository which has a method that accepts a Key and returns the specified resource in the users default culture.

We're going to want to leverage MVC's model DataAnnotations to bind our model to our razor views providing labels and validation etc.

My question is how do we achieve this so that it can talk to our ResourceProvider?

Do I need to implement a custom DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider? or is there a better/easier way to achieve this?

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Are you talking only about validation attributes and their corresponding error messages or more generally about things like DisplayName and so on ...?

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov Validation and DisplayName etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got a ready solution (that works with model and validation localization) which you can use: http://blog.gauffin.org/2011/09/easy-model-and-validation-localization-in-asp-net-mvc3/

All you need to do is to implement the [IStringProvider](https://github.com/jgauffin/griffin.mvccontrib/blob/master/source/Griffin.MvcContrib/Localization/Types/ILocalizedStringProvider.cs) interface to read from your own database instead.

**Update**

I've now written an [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/352583/Localization-in-ASP-NET-MVC-with-Griffin-MvcContri) about it.

Comment: Thanks for this. Does this method work based on convention i.e. Key names or is there a way to specify this as part of the Attribute? What I'm getting at is would I need to update existing keys for resources in the database?

Comment: I don't follow. The interface defines what the library asks for. You can use that information to query the proper values in your database.

Comment: OK thanks mate. Let me give this a further look and I'll let you know how I get on/update this thread. Much appreciated.

Comment: Hi. I've taken a look at your code and it's exactly what I need. Thanks. I noticed you have implemented a RepositoryStringProvider in the Types namespace that takes your repository as a constructor argument. This is similar to what I need but the problem I'm having is because the LocalizedStringProvider is a singleton and I don't want this lifetime for my repository or certanly the underlying dbcontext unit of work getting it via DI is difficult. How have you managed to overcome this?

Comment: @TomMiller: Read my article: www.codeproject.com/Articles/352583/Localization-in-ASP-NET-MVC-with-Griffin-MvcContri.

Comment: Hi mate. Great article - thanks for that. This is working great for me although could you answer me one a question. I'm receiving a strange error when using the System.Web.Mvc.CompareAttribute - I assume it's because it's not in System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations but not sure as the code is compiled as release. Thought you may know the answer otherwise I'm going to have to download the code and step through the LocalizedModelValidatorProvider.

Comment: Kind of hard to know when you just say `strange error` ;) Create an issue at github and include the complete exception.

Comment: lol - that's because it doesn't actually give me an error. Will do, nice1.

Comment: Hi mate. I've just updated to the newest release in Nuget which has some fixes for Compare and RegEx attributes. Thanks for this. For some reason the LocalizedModelValidatorProvider no longer accepts a stringProvider as a constructor argument. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: I had to refactor the provider to get it more stable. Sorry for breaking the api. All strings are now provided through this class: https://github.com/jgauffin/griffin.mvccontrib/blob/master/source/Griffin.MvcContrib/Localization/ValidationMessages/ValidationMessageProviders.cs

Comment: Thanks for this. I've just done an Update-Package Griffin.MvcContrib using Nuget which has pulled across the latest version v1.1.2.1. Is there any reason why it's adding NHibernate and FluentNHibernate bindings in my config files?

Comment: I just checked the package. It does not modify the config files or have any nhibernate dependnecies.

Comment: No worries. It's strange as it added a runtime node in the web config. I assume it must be something local to me.

Comment: Hi mate. I've got everything working with the new IValidationMessageDataStore. I'm just testing the CompareAttribute. The correct message is being pulled from the db but #g# is displayed in the UI. Any ideas why this is? Don't worry if it's not obvious as I'll just have to step through your code and work it out. Thanks in advance. Tom.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for, it's MVC2 targeted but should just as well work with MVC3 / MVC4:
http://carrarini.blogspot.com/2010/08/localize-aspnet-mvc-2-dataannotations.html

We did the same thing and in the end we went with the T4 Template if I'm not mistaken.